# How to choose with xpath script in html head?

Tags: xpath

How to choose with xpath script in html head?

Example(How to choose only ThisFile1.js?):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ThisFile1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="NotThisFile1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="NotThisFile2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="NotThisFile3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="NotThisFile4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, 
Yosef

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two one-liner XPath solutions and explanations what they select/return and which of them is more appropriate to use when. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/head/script/@src
```

or

```
string(/*/head/script/@src)
```

**The first XPath expression** selects all `src` attributes of all `script` elements that are childtren of all `head` elements that are children of the top element in the XML document.

**The second XPath expression** evaluates to the string value of the first of the attributes, selected by the first XPath expression. This would be most convenient if your XPath engine's API provides support for evaluting XPath expression that do not select nodes. If this is not the case you have to use the first XPath expression, then use the appropriate method/property of the API that returns the string value of the selected attribute node.